# Vue - namebased lazy component rendering in for loop

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Good morning, is there any way to render component "on fly" in code?

For example (semi-pseudocode):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template>
            <div class="text">
                <p
                    v-for="(component_to_render, index) in components_list"
                    :key="index"
                >
                    // and here instead of string it should load component from list
                    {{ component_to_render }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
// imports
export default {
    components: {
        Intro,
        UserData,
        ComponentA,
        ComponentB,
        ComponentC,
    },
    data () {
    return {
        components_list: [
            '<intro />',
            '<user-data />',
            '<component-a />',
            '<component-b />',
            '<component-c />',
        ]
    }
}
</script>
```

Now `{{ paragraph }}` in `v-for` returns strings from `components_list` list. Is there any way to instead of strings generate here these components "on fly"?

Maybe there is some function that I am not aware of. Tried to search for lazy loading but found answers only with lazy importing.

I don't need full answer, I would be grateful for showing direction what to search for.

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650633/blind-dynamic-load-vuejs-component-by-name-with-properties/59651404#59651404

Comment: Woah! This is it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michal Levý:

Working solution:

Component declaration in other file:

```
Vue.component('intro', Intro)
Vue.component('user-data', UserData)
Vue.component('component-a', ComponentA)
Vue.component('component-b', ComponentB)
Vue.component('component-c', ComponentC)
```

File from my question but now it is working properly:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template>
            <div class="text">
                <p
                    v-for="(component_to_render, index) in components_list"
                    :key="index"
                >
                    // instead of {{ component_to_render }}
                    <component v-bind:is="component_to_render"></component>
                </p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
// imports
export default {
    data () {
    return {
        components_list: [
            'intro',
            'user-data',
            'component-a',
            'component-b',
            'component-c',
        ]
    }
}
```